# Javascript Promises are not executed in the correct order

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a problem. I am trying to do the following:
I first check the url for a containing `agentId` parameter. Then I want to check in my database if the given `agentId` belongs to a valid agent. If so, then I want to store the entire object of that agent in a variable called `selectedAgent`. Then I want to use the `selectedAgent` in my next 2 functions.

The problem is that it gives me the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'active' of null` on line 106. This is caused by the fact that the last function in the chain gets executed before the rest. Here is the code:

```
const urlString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(urlString);
let selectedAgentId = urlParams.get('agentId');
let selectedAgent = null;


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {

    getStartupAgentData().then(fillAgentComboBox()).then(setToggleButtonContent());

});


function getStartupAgentData() {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'overview_get_agent_ajax.php',
            data: 'agentid=' + selectedAgentId, 
            dataType: 'text', 
            success: function(data) {
                selectedAgent = JSON.parse(data)[0];
                console.log(selectedAgent);
                resolve(true);
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Failed receiving agents")
                reject(true);
            }
        });
    });

}


function fillAgentComboBox() {

    console.log(selectedAgent);

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        getAllAgentData().then(function(agents) {
            
            let comboBoxAgent = document.getElementById("comboBoxAgent");

            for (let i = 0; i < agents.length; i++) {
                let option = document.createElement("option");
                
                // Agent data
                let id = agents[i].id;
                let owner = agents[i].owner;
                let exchange = agents[i].exchange;
                let remark = agents[i].remark;

                let text = "Agent " + id.toString().padStart(4, "0") + " - " + owner + " - " + exchange + " - " + remark;
                option.text = text;
                option.value = id;
                comboBoxAgent.add(option);

                if (selectedAgent === null) {
                    option.selected = true;
                    selectedAgent = agents[i];
                }
                else if (id === selectedAgentId) {
                    option.selected = true;
                    selectedAgent = agents[i];
                }
            }

            // Add agent id to url for other javascripts
            window.history.replaceState(null, null, "?agentId=" + selectedAgent.id);

            resolve(true);

        });

    });

}


function getAllAgentData() {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'overview_get_agents_ajax.php',
            data: '', 
            dataType: 'text', 
            success: function(data) {
                resolve(JSON.parse(data));
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                reject(true);
            }
        });
    });

}


function setToggleButtonContent() {

    let btnToggleAgent = document.getElementById("btnToggleAgent");

    if (selectedAgent.active == true) {
        btnToggleAgent.style.background = "#EE4141";
        btnToggleAgent.innerHTML = "Stop";
    }
    else {
        btnToggleAgent.style.background = "#44B642";
        btnToggleAgent.innerHTML = "Start";
    }

}
```

This is the error I get:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I suggest reading [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `then(fillAgentComboBox)` without the `()` which is calling your function in place and kicking it off immediately. You could also do `then(() => fillAgentComboBox())`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the functions to `.then` instead of invoking them and passing their return values.

```
getStartupAgentData().then(fillAgentComboBox).then(setToggleButtonContent);
```